# how to store text and image in the same column?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in SQL server 2008 R2 where I am storing values of translations.
The translated values can be a text or it can be an image also. We want to use same column for storing the image and text so when we do a search we don't have to give 2 queries based on type of data.
my question:-
1. Can I store image and text in the same column?
2. should I do that? or should i have 2 different columns? (one with varbinary and other simple nvarchar)?

Comment: Thank! one more query-
Is it because of the searching overhead you are suggesting I should use 2 columns?
I am wondering if i should use a different table all-together for image types..
any suggestions?

Comment: For best performance use even 2 different tables... and no it is not searching overhead but because it limits your possibilities in the future (for example to make a reverse query)...

Comment: @Yahia thanks but this has further confused me :) what you mean by 'Reverse query'? I am going ahead and creating 2 different columns one as nvarchar and one as varbinary(max)

Comment: "reverse queary" - someone gives you the translated text and wants to know what the original text(s) are...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to 1 - you can... just use a varbinary and handle everything else on the client side...

As to 2 - you **SHOULD NOT** use 1 column for both... but 2 columns (one varchar, one varbinary) !